# How to swipe tableviewcell for particular row in a section

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a custom `UITableview` which is diveded into sections, I have implemented `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` into it.  When I swipe my table view cell, a `UIButton` appears. The problem I am now facing is when I swipe the first table view cell, another cell in successive sections also recognizes the swipe gesture. I am not able to find how to swipe a cell of particular a section without other cells of other sections getting swiped.

I just want to swipe, I don't want to delete/insert or add check marks.

**UPDATE**.... This is my **customCell.m
 Tableview = customTableView**

```
       - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
        {
            self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
            if (self)
            {
                self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

                self.symptomCellImageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;


                swipeButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
                swipeButton .frame = CGRectMake(220.0, 8.0, 30.0, 30.0);
                swipeButton .hidden = NO;

}
```

**In my MainViewController.m**

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad
    {        

         symptomSwipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandleLeft)];
         symptomSwipeLeft .numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
         symptomSwipeLeft .direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
         [customTableView addGestureRecognizer:symptomSwipeLeft];
         [self addGestureRecognizer:symptomSwipeRight];

          symptomSwipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandleRight)];
           symptomSwipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
           symptomSwipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
           [customTableView addGestureRecognizer:symptomSwipeRight];
           [self addGestureRecognizer:symptomSwipeRight];

    }


- (void)swipeHandleLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)aSwipeGestureRecognizer
{
     CGPoint location = [aSwipeGestureRecognizer locationInView:customTableView ];
     NSIndexPath * indexPath = [customTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

     if(indexPath)
{
        UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell *)[customTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       [cell.swipeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(secondPageButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

              }
}



- (void)swipeHandleRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)aSwipeGestureRecognizer
 {
     CGPoint location = [aSwipeGestureRecognizer locationInView:customTableView ];
     NSIndexPath * indexPath = [customTableViewindexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

     if(indexPath)
{
       UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell *)[customTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.swipeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(secondPageButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
              }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)aSwipeGestureRecognizer; {
  CGPoint location = [aSwipeGestureRecognizer locationInView:_tableView];
  NSIndexPath * indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

  if(indexPath){
    UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell *)[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell whateverMethodYouWant];
  }
}
```

As a side note, the reason you are getting calls to multiple cells is because the row is not unique enough. There is a `row = 0` in all of you sections. Therefore, if you want each cell to have a unique number attached to its `.tag` property, you would need to know the largest number of rows in any section (call it `largestNumberOfRows`), and then compute:

`cell.swipeButton.tag = (indexPath.section * largestNumberOfRows) + indexPath.row;`

Hope that helps!

***EDIT:***

To use the above method, in your `viewDidLoad;` method, add the following code:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
[_tableView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

***EDIT 2***

Looking at your code, you have put your gesture recognizers in the wrong file. Here is the setup:

In your `MainViewController.m` file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad; {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UISwipeGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
  [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
  [_tableView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)aSwipeGestureRecognizer; {
  CGPoint location = [aSwipeGestureRecognizer locationInView:_tableView];
  NSIndexPath * indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

  if(indexPath){
    UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell *)[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(aSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight){
      [cell symptomCellSwipeRight];
    }
    else if(aSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft){
      [cell symptomCellSwipeLeft];
    }
  }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
  // Initial your cell. Then add:
  [cell.swipeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(secondPageButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

In your `PPsymptomTableCell.m` file:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier; {
  if((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])){
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.symptomCellImageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

    // SHARE ON FACEBOOK BUTTON //

    shareFacebookButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    shareFacebookButton.frame = CGRectMake(220.0, 8.0, 30.0, 30.0);
    shareFacebookButton.hidden = NO;

    // DISPLAY NOTIFICATION IMAGE //

    selectedCellImageDisplay = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedSymptomImage.png"]];
    selectedCellImageDisplay.frame = CGRectMake(240.0, 8.0, 30.0, 30.0);

    // SYMPTOM NAME //

    symptomCellLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15.0,0.0 ,280.0,40.0)];
    symptomCellLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Rockwell" size:17];
    symptomCellLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    symptomCellLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [self.contentView addSubview:symptomCellLabel];
    [self.contentView addSubview:selectedCellImageDisplay];
    [self.contentView addSubview:shareFacebookButton];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)symptomCellSwipeLeft; {
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"HideView" context:nil];
  symptomCellLabel.frame = CGRectMake(-183.0, 0.0, 280.0, 40.0);
  selectedCellImageDisplay.frame = CGRectMake(-340.0, 8.0, 30.0, 30.0);
  shareFacebookButton.frame = CGRectMake(120.0, 8.0, 80.0, 30.0);
  shareFacebookButton.hidden = NO;
  shareFacebookButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (void)symptomCellSwipeRight; {
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"HideView" context:nil];
  symptomCellLabel.frame = CGRectMake(15.0,0.0 ,280.0,40.0);
  selectedCellImageDisplay.frame = CGRectMake(240.0, 8.0, 30.0, 30.0);
  shareFacebookButton.frame = CGRectMake(220.0, 8.0, 30.0, 30.0);
  shareFacebookButton.hidden = YES;

  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This should get everything working nicely.

Comment: ..shouldn't i call the  [cell.swipeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(intoView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] in cellForRowAtIndexPath

and the tag should be done in cellForRowAtIndexPath right

Comment: My code will take your `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and give you the exact cell that the user is swiping on. From there, you can call whatever method you like. So if you want the swipe button to appear, just call `cell.swipeButton.hidden = !cell.swipeButton.hidden` (this will make the button unhide if it's hidden or vice-versa). You could even call a custom cell method to make the button animate in! No need for the `.tag` property at all!

Comment: Thanks :)... i'll look into it ..just one more thing if i swipe a cell in 1st section ,then cell in other sections doesn't get swiped right

Comment: No, the code I gave you will select only 1 cell, so none of the other cells will be changed.

Comment: Yes, but that is for a different question.

Comment: @msgambel..it didnt work..it didnt call the method...what about largestNumberOfRows = 0...should i initialize this in handleSwipeMethod ?   my tableviewcell is a custom cell

Comment: What is your method `secondPageButton`?

Comment: secondPageButton goes into facebook page   .....   where have i gone wrong ?..i have added swipebutton in customcell

Comment: When you write `[cell.swipeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(secondPageButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`, you are adding the method as a target that the button will call when the user *touches up inside* the button. If you want to call the method on the swipe, use: `[self secondPageButton];`.

Comment: .....let me where i am going wrong in **customcell.mfile** 
**swipe button** is declared , **swipe handle method** is declared (how will i call **secondPageButton method** since its declared **in mainViewController.m file**)

MainViewController - **secondPageButton method is declared**

Comment: `handleSwipe:` should also be declared in your `MainViewController.m` file. If you want to activate the button on swipe, call `[self secondPageButton];`. If you want to hide/unhide the button on swipe, use: `cell.swipeButton.hidden = !cell.swipeButton.hidden`, and in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, add `[cell.swipeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(secondPageButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`. That will cause the button to unhide, and then if the user touches the button, the `secondPageButton:` method will be called.

Comment: I opened the link and posted the code you needed to solve the problem in my answer under ***Edit 2***.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that anymore. The methods above will swipe only one cell. I added that in to explain to you why your attempt was not working.

Comment: i added ur code ..when i swipe a button multiple swipes is occurred in other sections as well

Comment: This can't be the case. This will work for sure. Are you sure you're setting up your tableview and cells properly? You can easily test that this is giving the proper `indexPath` by making a dummy tableview and cells and swiping. There must be some other issue. What is most likely happening is that your reusable cell is the problem. Make sure when the cell is loaded that the button is hidden. Does your data model even keep track of this?

Comment: .yes ..i hide the button when i swipe it to right ..when i scroll uitableview then multiple cells in different sections gets swiped...i'll mail the project to you  i kind of did a work around ..in cellForRowAtIndexPath `if(cell == nil) { cell=[[PPsymptomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault **reuseIdentifier:nil**]; }` will it be ok if i do it this way reuseIdentifier:nil –

Comment: Let me know if u have d/w the project..if not i'll put the link once again

Comment: @msgambel..were u able to figure it out?

Comment: I haven't had time to look at it. I will respond once I do.

Comment: hi..were u able to find out where the problem was ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you repost the project. You seem to have taken the link off.

Comment: how about now ??...PPSymtomTableCell is my custom cell

Comment: Got it. I'll check it out an repost later.

Comment: 2 things: 1. The `UISwipeGestureRecognizers` need to be in your `PPViewController` like I described above. 2. You are not storing in the data if the `remedyLabel` is visible or not. There are 2 ways to do this; either make a method called `reset` in the `PPtableCell` that moves the `remedyLabel` back to the original spot, and call `reset` after `cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];`. Or, you can store a `BOOL` value in your `searchSymptomsArray` that marks if the cell is showing the `remedyLabel` or not, and move it after you `dequeue` the cell.

Comment: That's fine. The same logic applies for the button.

Comment: ..remedyLabel is in other tableview ..swipegesture is in symptomTableView..when u swipe the first tableviewcell when u load the app u will see a red button ..when u scroll the tableview other cells in section gets swiped

Comment: My comments explains how to fix this. Replace `remedyLabel` with your red button, and it will work out exactly the same. The comment will solve your problem.

Comment: ..thanks it worked :) i created reset method in customtableviewcell and called that method in cellForRowAtIndexPath after dequeueReusableCell 
`cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        [cell reset];
    
        if (cell==nil)
{
}`

Comment: just one more thing..when u tap on any of the first tableviewcell .u will see another tableviewcell ..when u swipe u will see a uiswitch and if u switch it ON and go back to first tableview .u will see an image indicating that switch is ON for that cell.. i am storing the switch state in an array called `selectedSymptIPArray` in cellForRowAtIndexPath ..the image is not appearing correctly like if i scroll the image disappears and in other sections images arent showing up (if uiswitch is ON)

Comment: `selectedSymptIPArray` is storing junk values .. i know this is based on another question .since u have the project can u let me know where i am going wrong.

Comment: It'll be something you'll have to take care of in the `reset` method. What's happening is, when the `cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];` is called, it's taking the cell that's in memory. If that cell already has the switch on, it will stay that way unless you tell it to do something otherwise. I'd suggest playing with the `reset` method, or making another method that you call after `reset` to fix the problem, but it's essentially the same idea. You should post new questions from now on though, as this is not the way stackoverflow is supposed to run.

Comment: ok....the problem which i am facing is selectedSymptIPArray is storing junk values

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing your table with `sections`, then make your tag value of combination of `indexPath.sections` and `indexPath.row`.

But make sure you are implementing without overlapping of tagValue.